# How to strike text on swipe when I'm using a recycleView

Tags: android

I'm trying to strike a text on swipe.

I'm using ItemTouchHelper

```
        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
          // I guess here I should highlight the text, but when I'm swiping the slide is replaced with something else. So It would be nice to have same thing, but with text striked and a checkbox checked..
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(list_list);
```

Comment: So when user swipe left item of recyclerview should have checked checkbox and stroked text, right?

Comment: I already have for each item a checkbox, a CheckBox,TextView and 2 TextInputLayout. So yes, check the checkbox and strike TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ItemTouchHelper should look like so:

```
    final List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, list);
    ....  
    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
        @Override
        public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
            return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE, swipeFlags);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            Item item = list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
```

Explenation: `list` is source of your items in my case I created `Item` class that looks like so:

```
private class Item {
    private String mText;
    private boolean mIsChecked;

    Item(String text, boolean isChecked) {
        mText = text;
        mIsChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        mIsChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mIsChecked;
    }
}
```

Same list of `Item` objects is passed to Adapter. So on swipe event we need to modify state of `Item` object and notify `Adapter` that particular item changed, which will lead to redraw of that item through call to `onBindViewHolder`. Which in my case looks like so:

```
private static class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemVH> {
    List<Item> mContent;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        super();
        mContent = items;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item_view, parent, false);
        return new ItemVH(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemVH holder, int position) {
        Item item = mContent.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(item.getText());
        //Make a stroke according to checked state
        holder.text.setPaintFlags(getFlagsForChecked(holder.text.getPaintFlags(), item.isChecked()));

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(item.isChecked());
    }

    private int getFlagsForChecked(int origin, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            return origin | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG;
        } else {
            return origin & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContent.size();
    }
}
```

In `onBindViewHolder` we bind state of `Item` object to dedicated view through ViewHolder. Here you can make all required changes to text, style etc. to represent state of item object.